# Get directory name from path of %CD%

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Given that the current directory, `%CD%` is

```
C:\Parent\Child
```

In a batch file, how can I get the value `Child` in to a variable?

thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
for %%a in (.) do set currentfolder=%%~na
echo %currentfolder%
```

From here: https://superuser.com/questions/160702/get-current-folder-name-by-a-dos-command

Comment: It is almost correct, but it doesn't print the extension of the directory. E.g: in case of `c:\parent\child.01`. An additional 'x' character should be added to work correctly: `currentfolder=%%~nxa`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer

```
for %%a in ("%cd%") do set folder=%%~na
echo.%folder%
pause
```

Comment: This should not work! Supposedly, the `%~` modifiers can only be used on file or folder names, but `"%cd%"` is a STRING! Apparently, the string is processed as a name no matter its contents. Try this: `for %a in ("@:\one;\two()\three=+") do echo %~da %~na %~fa`

Answer (score 1):

or you can do something like this

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%a IN (.) DO SET currentfolder=%%~nxa
ECHO %currentfolder%
```

Answer (score 0):

@manojlds's answer is not correct for all cases.

The `%%~nI` shortcut works fine for files, but not for directories.

**Example:**

*C:\a..o\ex.bat*

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%a IN (.) DO SET currentfolder=%%~na
ECHO %currentfolder%
```

If I execute this batch file from its location, the output is `"a."`:

```
C:\a..o\>ex.bat
a.
```

**Solution:**

A possible solution is the following:

*C:\sol.bat*

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET cwd="\%~f1"
SET name=""
:extract
    SET char="%cwd:~-2,-1%"
    IF NOT %char%=="\" (
        SET cwd="%cwd:~1,-2%"
        SET name="%char:~1,-1%%name:~1,-1%"
        GOTO :extract
    )
ECHO %name%
ENDLOCAL
```

**Tests:**

```
C:\>sol.bat "@!%#"
"@!%#"
C:\>sol.bat a..o
"a..o"
```