# Proper file locations

Tags: batch-file, cygwin, batch-processing, ls, file-listing

We have been having some issues where people have been putting files into the folder for the wrong job number. files for `664585_custnum_qty_filetype.dat` should be in folder `664585` I am looking for a way to make sure that the files in a given folder all start with the foldername. I have been working with.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /R "V:\Work" %%G in (.) DO (
 Pushd %%G
 REM Echo now in %%G
 for %%a in (.) do set currentfolder=%%~na
    echo %currentfolder%
    REM this is where I would be finding files that dont start the right way.
 Popd )
 Echo "back home"
Pause
```

trying to combine two other things that I have seen for [iterating through folders](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) and [finding current directory name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071458/get-directory-name-from-path-of-cd)

Ultimately I want to list all the files that are out of place so that I can find them and figure out why they're not/who put them there. So I would like to have a program that iterated through all of the folders in `V:\work` into folders like `665485` and `332185 CustName` displaying any files which do not start with `665485` or `332185` respectively.

I do have cygwin on my system, though not enabled all the time, and was considering ls, referencing `C:\cygwin\bin\ls.exe` directly to avoid it throwing off the normal functionality of some MS commands with the same name.

Any suggestions on how to get my list of files that dont start with the number from the foldername?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /d %%i in (*) do (if "%%i" NEQ "xArchive" (for /f %%j in ("%%i") do (dir "%%i" /b|for /f %%k in ('find "%%j" /v') do @dir "%%k" /b /s|find "thumbs.db" /v /i|find "xArchive" /v /i))
```

put this in the directory that contains the numbered folders and run it there. I'll be back in a few hours If you need me to change it. ;)

Comment: This is working like a charm. I get a few various "File Not Found" Errors, but it also spits out exactly what I needed. One small change that I made was, since I'm trying to run this on an automated basis, I directed output to a file `zzz.txt` (which also had the side benefit of dropping the "File Not Found" since it was error text) and then sending that file as an attachment to myself.

Comment: My only additional thing that would be on my wishlist is an "ignore" option, because right now it also reports several Thumbs.db type files  that would be nice to ignore. It's simple to ingore those, but it would be nice.

Comment: Perfect again! ignore a folder called xArchive?

Comment: my last request is for an explanation of what it is iterating through. I can see that it is checking for xArchive and see where it filters out any Thumbs.db, but right now the middle is a magical glob to me :)

Comment: for /d makes the wildcard match dirs, for /f... gets the first group of characters in the name and ignores everything after the first space. it then dir's the dir found in the first loop and pipes that to a find for loop which processes the output and does a recursive dir on it which outputs all occurrences (in this case only one) of the file, with the full path. sorry that came out jumbled, I'm only thirteen and don't have much teaching experience.